# React native: "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child"

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, native

Have googled the entire day and found similar problems but no answers that fixes my problem. It seems as though the "timeLeft" put as the "until" under countdown is an object, even though the log (typeof timeLeft) says that it's a number (as it's supposed to be).

I get errormessage:
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```js
render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView>
          <View>  
          {
            this.state.auctions.map(async (auctionObject, index) => {
              var timeLeft = await this.getTimeLeft(auctionObject.expiration);
              console.log(JSON.stringify(timeLeft) + typeof timeLeft)
              
              return <View style={styles.auctionObject} key={index + 'a'}>
                <Text key={index + 'b'} onPress={() => this._renderObjectPage(auctionObject)}>
                  TITLE: {auctionObject.title} {"\n"}
                  HIGHEST BID: {auctionObject.highestBid} {"\n"}
                  NUMBER OF LIKES:{auctionObject.numberOfLikes}
                </Text>
                <CountDown key={index + 'c'}
                  until={timeLeft}
                  timetoShow={('H', 'M', 'S')}
                  size={12}
                />
                </View>
            } 
            )
          }
          </View>
          </ScrollView>
```

Thank you

Comment: Beware of anything async inside your render

Comment: All right! If I remove async the timeLeft variable is not resolved and becomes Object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72})

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your render function is outputting a list of Promise objects (which isn't valid react code):

```
this.state.auctions.map(async (auctionObject, index) => {
              var timeLeft = await this.getTimeLeft(auctionObject.expiration);
```

Question: Are you sure that the getTimeLeft operation needs to be async? If so then this operation will need to be done outside of the render function (possibly in componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate).

If you can change getTimeLeft to be synchronous, it will work:

```
this.state.auctions.map((auctionObject, index) => {
              var timeLeft = this.getTimeLeft(auctionObject.expiration);
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! Might there be a way to put "await" in front of, say, the "return" inside the mapping to make sure that the promises are resolved before rendering?

Comment: nw - no absolutely not - the render function is designed to be synchronous since this function can be called at any time and sometimes many times per second. Your component should have another mechanism by which it resolves the data (like I suggested above) and the render function simply outputs the html code based on the data saved in state.